# Convert json to other json structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have an array of objects with this structure:

```
const treeData = [
  { 0: ["0-0", "0-1"] },
  { 1: ["1-0", "1-1"] }
]
```

It could be deeper but array data would be always json or strings

```
const treeData = [
  { 0: ["0-0", "0-1"] },
  { 1: ["1-0", "1-1"] },
    2,
    3
]
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
const treeDataResult = [
  {
    label: "0",
    value: "0",
    children: [
      {
        label: "0-0",
        value: "0-0"
      },
      {
        label: "0-1",
        value: "0-1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "1",
    value: "1",
    children: [
      {
        label: "1-0",
        value: "1-0",
      },
      {
        label: "1-1",
        value: "1-1",
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    label: "2",
    value: "2"
  },
  { 
    label: "3",
    value: "3"
  }
]
```

My code right now is this:

```js
const treeData = [
      { "0": ["0-0", "0-1"] },
      { "1" : ["1-0", "1-1"] }
    ];

const convertNode = (parentNode) =>
  parentNode.map(
    childnode => {
      if (typeof(childNode) === 'string')
        return {
          label: childNode,
          value: childNode
        }
      else
        return
      childNode.map((key, val) =>
        ({
          label: key,
          value: key,
          children: convertNode(val)
        })
      )
    }
  )

var treeDataResult = convertNode(treeData);
console.log(treeDataResult);
```

Comment: What does not work in your current code?

Comment: The `typeof` of `2` and `3` would be `"number"`, not `"string"`. Also if your node is an object, it might not be an array - you need to actually get that single key you're (ab)using as a label.

Comment: You cannot have an enter after return. If you want it on a new line then do: `return ( (new line here ok)childNode.map... )`

Comment: You mistake JavaScript objects for JSON. They are not the same. JSON is *always* a string.

Comment: Objects like `{ 0 : "foo" }` and `{ 1: "bar" }` are bad when the key is a variable. In order for your program to extract the key's value, `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` must be used. Compared to something like `{ key: 0, value: "foo" }` where `key` and `value` are known – extracting each value is just a matter of reading their respective properties.

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1):

*If the shape of your data is correct* I've used reduce and map to get the data into the correct shape and the rest operator so that the objects are in one array

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    0: ["0-0", "0-1"]
  },
  {
    1: ["1-0", "1-1"]
  },
  {
    2: null
  },
  {
    3: []
  },
  {
    4: ["0-1"]
  }
]

const changeShape = data => {
  return data.reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...shape(curr)], []);
}

const shape = item => Object.keys(item).map(key => data(item, key));

const data = (item, key) => {
  return !item[key] || !item[key].length > 0 ?
    labelValue(key) : 
    {
      ...labelValue(key),
      children: item[key].map(i => labelValue(i))
    }
}

const labelValue = v => {
  return {
    label: v,
    value: v
  }
}

console.log(changeShape(treeData))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `JSON.parse` is used to get the data, you can try something like this:

```js
var j = '[ { "0": ["0-0", "0-1"] }, { "1": ["1-0", "1-1"] }, 2, 3 ]'

var o = JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => (k = v.constructor) === Array ? v : 
  k !== Object ? ({ label: v, value: v }) :
  ({ label: k = Object.keys(v)[0], value: k,  children: v[k] }) )

console.log( o )
```

Answer (score 0):

a primitive solution

```js
    const treeData = [
          { 0 : ["0-0", "0-1"] },
          { 1 : ["1-0", "1-1"] }
        ]
        
        let treeDataResult = [];
        
        
        for(i = 0; i < treeData.length; i++) {
          let current = treeData[i],
          label = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(current),
        
          obj = {
            label: label,
            value: label,
            children: []
          }
          
         for(j = 0; j < current[i].length; j++) {
            let childData = current[i][j],
            child = {
            label : childData,
            value : childData
          } 
          obj.children.push(child)  
         }
        treeDataResult.push(obj)
        }

       console.log(JSON.stringify(treeDataResult, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const treeData = [
  { "0": ["0-0", "0-1"] },
  { "1" : ["1-0", "1-1"] }
];

const convertNode = (parentNode) => {
  console.log(parentNode)
  return parentNode.map(
    childNode => {
      if (typeof childNode === 'string')
        return {
          label: childNode,
          value: childNode
        }
      else
        return {
          label: Object.entries(childNode)[0][0],
          value: Object.entries(childNode)[0][0],
          children: convertNode(Object.entries(childNode)[0][1])
        }
    }
  )
}
```